# Distance and width in Spark AR scripting

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I'm having a hard time navigating Spark AR documentation and I couldn't find an answer to this: I have three planes in a Scene. Two of them are moving, one of them static.

- How can I get the distance between those two planes?
- How can I change the width of the third plane to that distance?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in luck because the [Reactive Module](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/reference/classes/reactivemodule) just so happens to have a built-in distance function!

```
//import the Reactive module
const Reactive = require('Reactive');

//find your planes
let plane1 = Scene.root.find('plane1');
let plane2 = Scene.root.find('plane2');
let plane3 = Scene.root.find('plane3');

//create point signals
let point1 = Reactive.pack3(plane1.transform.x, plane1.transform.y, plane1.transform.z);
let point2 = Reactive.pack3(plane2.transform.x, plane2.transform.y, plane2.transform.z);

//get the distance between the two points
let distance = Reactive.distance(point1, point2);

//apply scale
plane3.transform.scaleX = distance;
```

Good luck!